# Does the specific chair matter in this case?

Tags: probability

Eleven chairs are numbered 1 through 11. Four girls and seven boys sit on these
chairs at random. What is the probability that chair 5 is occupied by a boy? Is it 7/11 or does the fact that the chair number is specified play a role?

Comment: I presume "at random" means with a uniform distribution. If so, why should the number of the chair matter?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Because added information can have all sorts of subtle effects that trip up people who brush off details like this. How is a student to know that *this* happens to be one of the instances where the seemingly obvious method is actually correct? (that's not a rhetorical question -- a way to distinguish which 'obvious' simplifications are right and which are mistakes is something one needs to efficiently and correctly solve probability problems)

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. To the chair, the probability of a boy sitting on it is 7/11.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to see why you are correct with $7/11$ and the chairs being numbered don't matter. Let's decide who sits in chair $5$ first then decide the rest of the chairs afterwards. We have $7$ guys to choose for that particular chair, then we have $10$ remaining people for the next chair, $9$ for the next, and so on, so our numerator is $7*10!$

The total number of ways to seat them is $11!$

So, simplifying, the probably a guy sits in seat $5$ is $$\frac{7*10!}{11!} =\frac{ 7*(10*9*8*...*2*1)}{11*(10*9*8*...*2*1)} = \frac{7}{11}$$